Are helicopters required a higher drop/impact test than airplanes?
Considering an airplane and a helicopter both with similar weight and number of seats and both to be certified in the same category.
Are helicopters required a higher standard than airplanes due to  its vertical flight nature or is it actually the opposite or there are no differences?

I think you should see 14 CFR Parts 27 and 29 for helicopters and 14 CFR Parts 23 and 25 for airplanes.
